# code igniter instalation - only default controller loads

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

Running codeIgniter for the first time, ran it on my linux mint system and Fedora, *2 different local servers*, and got the same problem:

-Apart from the default controller, any other controller returns 404

and if i change the default controller or default method in the configs the *new default loads properly.*

Found a few people with the same problem, and it seems to be some config done wrong, but i cant find what it is in my case.

**Solutions tried:**

The official documentation offers a couple of solutions, as changing the `$uriProtocol` in App.php, and/or and using `$indexPage = 'index.php?';`(with ? in the end) none worked.

people suggested using `index.php/controller` in the url, to access it, but it also didn't work.

my application is running in http://localhost:8080 , and my base url is set `$baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/';`

my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

server config:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Any other suggestion on what to try???

Comment: Make sure to match capitalisations in filenames and paths on Linux. We've noticed that sometimes mismatching e.g. "Controller.php"  with "controller.php" causes unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not that,
capitalization was a concern in all attempts - but to be sure, just checked again, not the case...

Comment: P2GR requested this "Could you post your full virtual host configuration?"